# How can I copy a file to every user's home dir in BASH?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I'm trying to copy a file to each user's home directory. Ideally, the file would be chown/chgrp but that's not really the question I'm asking. my real question is how to select every subdirectory with a wildcard.

```
$ touch testfile
$ sudo cp testfile /home/*/
```

This successfully copies the file to the current user's directory, but for every other user, I get

```
cp: omitting directory '/home/user2/'
cp: omitting directory '/home/user3/'
```

And so on. 
Thanks in advance for the answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` does not take multiple targets, so you'll have to provide the loop yourself. The direct equivalent of what you're trying to do should be

```
for homedir in /home/*; do sudo cp testfile "$homedir"; done
```

with the usual caveats: assuming you have no spaces in usernames, assuming home directories are exactly the ones in `/home` (otherwise, you need to get the home directory location out of `/etc/passwd`, but that includes system users, so you'd want to look at only those with a high-enough UID, and where user UIDs start is distribution-dependant).

Comment: While ```cp``` indeed doesn't accept multiple targets, [xargs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/195972/2303098 "How to copy a file to multiple directories using the gnu cp command") could save a few calls to ```sudo``` in this specific example: ```echo /home/* | sudo xargs -n 1 cp testfile```. This may or may not matter much, depending on how many home directories are involved here.

Comment: I definitely need to learn to use `xargs`. That's like awesome Linux magic stuff I'm ashamed not to know. But on that note, wouldn't your code also replace all regular files in the users' home directory with `testfile`?

Comment: @StephenC: in my personal opinion, do `find` first if you're unfamilliar with it.

Comment: @StephenC: `cp` and `mv` (and others) have that weird do-what-I-mean semantics where if the target exists and is a directory, they copy/move into instead of overwriting.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz `mkdir ./testdir ; touch ./testfile{0..3} ; echo "testfile 4" > testfile4 ; echo ./* | xargs -n 1 cp testfile4 ; cat ./testfile* ./testdir/*` -- I'm pretty sure your xargs example will break my system.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz Okay, okay, alright. I see where my logic was flawed. I actually spun up a Docker ubuntu container to try it out. Of course it would NOT replace all the files in the home directories, but it WOULD replace any files that might live in /home/

Comment: The code in this answer actually supports any characters in directory names (`for f in *` will iterate once for each file that `*` expanded to, not once for each whitespace-separated token).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @UlrichSchwarz for the idea to do this within a loop. For my own peace of mind, I added a check to ensure regular files don't get overwritten.

```
# First command-line arg is the file to be copied
for homedir in /home/* ; do 
    if [ -d "$homedir" ] ; then
         cp $1 "$homedir"
         user=$(ls -ld $homedir | awk '{print $3}')
         chown --verbose $user:$user $homedir/$1
    fi
done
```

This also opens the door to relatively easily solve my "nice-to-have," which was changing group and user ownership.

Comment: You could also include the slash `for homedir in /home/*/ ; do` will match only directories under /home, so you shouldn't need the `-d` test. Also, since you are only doing one thing, you could (if you want to keep the test) easily rewrite the body of the loop as simply `test -d "$homedir" && cp $1 "$homedir"`. The benfits of `if` are more clear once you are doing multiple things in response to a conditional.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling -- Cool. The `/home/*/` thing makes sense. Thank you. For the record, I used the conditional block so logic could be added to `chown` the file after it gets copied.

Comment: And if you want it to be in any user created in the future add it to /etc/skel

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -1 /home/ | xargs -rI{} sudo cp testfile /home/{}/
```

Explanation

`ls -1 /home/` selects all users' selects all users' home directories listing them by one in a line.

`xargs -rI{}` executes the following command separately for each entry on standard input and substitutes `{}` with the text of the entry (user's directory in our case).

`cp testfile /home/{}/` copies your `testfile` to the home directory of the user.